# finding change in x and y given two points and length of vector

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, vector

I have a bullet shot from the first point(the player location), and it needs to travel towards the second point(the mouse click), at a given speed.

Right now I have all this code.

cx and cy marks center of player or point one
while MouseX and MouseY represent the cordinates of the mous click

```
if MouseX < cx:              #determines direction of bullet
    direction = 'left'
else:
    direction = 'right'

if (cx-MouseX) != 0:
    new_slope = (cy - MouseY) / (cx - MouseX)
else:
    new_slope = 'undefined'             #determines slope and b value to get the equation of the line
                                        #that the bullet travels on 
    
if new_slope != 'undefined':    
    b_value = ((-1)*(new_slope)*(cx))+(cy)
else:
    b_value = None
```

and

```
if self.direction == 'right':
        if self.slope != 'undefined':
            if self.slope > 0 or self.slope < 0 and self.slope != 0:
                if self.slope < 1 or self.slope > -1:
                    float(self.bx)
                    float(bullet_speed)
                    self.by = (self.slope*(self.bx+bullet_speed)+self.b_value)
                    self.bx = ((self.by - self.b_value)/self.slope)
                else:
                    float(self.bx)
                    float(bullet_speed)
                    self.bx = (((self.by+bullet_speed) - self.b_value)/self.slope)
                    self.by = (self.slope*(self.bx)+self.b_value)
        else:
            self.bx = self.bx + bullet_speed
                
    else:
        if self.slope != 'undefined':
            if self.slope > 0 or self.slope < 0:
                if self.slope < 1 or self.slope > -1:
                    self.by = (self.slope*(self.bx-bullet_speed)+self.b_value)
                    self.bx = ((self.by - self.b_value)/self.slope)
                elif self.slope == 0:
                    self.bx -= bullet_speed
                else:
                    self.bx = (((self.by-bullet_speed) - self.b_value)/self.slope)
                    self.by = (self.slope*(self.bx)+self.b_value)
            else:
                self.bx = self.bx - bullet_speed
```

It is extremely messy and causes my bullets to increase in speed when shot up or down, and go slow when shot to the left or right.

However, i am at a loss at what i should do to change the code to allow my bullets to travel at the same speed regardless of the angle shot. If someone good at math and tkinter and such could help that would so greatly appreciated.

(As a side note , all my objects are Tkinter canvas items so they must move by whole integers)

Comment: probably this image be will too hard for you - [Calculate position having angle and speed or distance](https://imgur.com/W0PitDa). If you have `speed` and `angle` then you have to use `sin()`, `cos()` to calculate `delta_x`, `delta_y` and then you have to add it to current position.

Comment: Too get `angle` between two points you may have to use ``math.atan2(dy, dx)`  - it returns `angle` in radians but `sin()`/`cos()` also need radians.

Comment: Oh okay this makes a lot of sense. Thank you! @furas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I didn't make mistake - I don't remeber it too well.

**EDIT:** there was mistake in `atan2(dy, dx)` - has to be `atan2(dx, dy)`

---

It calculate new position (after one frame/move) if you have bullet's position and speed, and target's 
position.

You have to repeat it

```
import math

speed = 10

# bullet current position
x1 = 0
y1 = 0

# taget possition
x2 = 100
y2 = 100

dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1

angle = math.atan2(dx, dy)
#print(math.degrees(angle))

cx = speed * math.sin(angle)
cy = speed * math.cos(angle)
#print(cx, cy)

# bullet new current position
x1 += cx
y1 += cy

print(x1, y1)
```

---

**EDIT:** Example with loop

**EDIT:** It needs `abs()` in `if abs(cx) < abs(dx) or abs(cy) < abs(dy):`

**BTW:** if `target` doesn't change place or `bullet` doesn't change `angle` then you can calculate `cx,cy` only once.

```
import math

def move(x1, y1, x2, y2, speed):

    # distance
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1

    # angle
    angle = math.atan2(dx, dy)
    #print(math.degrees(angle))

    # 
    cx = speed * math.sin(angle)
    cy = speed * math.cos(angle)
    #print(cx, cy)

    # if distance is smaller then `cx/cy`
    # then you have to stop in target.
    if abs(cx) < abs(dx) or abs(cy) < abs(dy):
        # move bullet to new position
        x1 += cx
        y1 += cy
        in_target = False
    else:
        # move bullet to target
        x1 = x2
        y1 = y2
        in_target = True

    return x1, y1, in_target

#--- 

speed = 10

# bullet position
x1 = 10
y1 = 0

# taget possition
x2 = 120
y2 = 10

print('x: {:6.02f} | y: {:6.02f}'.format(x1, y1))

in_target = False

while not in_target:
    x1, y1, in_target = move(x1, y1, x2, y2, speed)
    print('x: {:6.02f} | y: {:6.02f}'.format(x1, y1))
```

Result

```
x:  10.00 | y:   0.00
x:  19.96 | y:   0.91
x:  29.92 | y:   1.81
x:  39.88 | y:   2.72
x:  49.84 | y:   3.62
x:  59.79 | y:   4.53
x:  69.75 | y:   5.43
x:  79.71 | y:   6.34
x:  89.67 | y:   7.24
x:  99.63 | y:   8.15
x: 109.59 | y:   9.05
x: 119.55 | y:   9.96
x: 120.00 | y:  10.00
```

**BTW:** if `target` doesn't change place or `bullet` doesn't change `angle` then you can calculate `cx,cy` only once.

Comment: I add example with loop

Comment: correction: it needs `abs()` in `if abs(cx) < abs(dx) or abs(cy) < abs(dy):`

Comment: btw: if `target` doesn't change place or `bullet` doesn't change `angle` then you can calculate `cx,cy` only once.